# Ionic: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property ‘length’ of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

This is my typescript code

```
export class FailedPage {

  failedjobs: Array<any> = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
              public navParams: NavParams, public jobfailList: JobActionsProvider) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('FailedPage');
    // getting jobs from job-actions file and displaying
    this.jobfailList.getfailedjobList().then((data) => {
      console.log('displaying failed job list');
      for (let values of data) {
        this.failedjobs.push(values);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

I’m facing error as

> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property ‘length’ of
>   undefined TypeError: Cannot read property ‘length’ of undefined at
>   failed.ts:24

Here 24 line is `for (let values of data)` How can I fix this?

Comment: I think data is return as object so please console it

Comment: check if data is null/undefined...before the loop of course

Comment: displaying failed job listundefined. this is what it is displaying in the console.

Comment: That should be the issue, data is undefined and hence the issue. Adding an IF condition should solve the error

Comment: can you elaborate it?

Answer (score 0):

The response from the api can be data.data it depends of your backend